# 2 simple objects not rotating correctly

Tags: c++, opengl

So basicly i want to rotate 2 objects differently(Pyramid and Cube). 
  I used for both objects before rendering glRotatef() function with different values. 
  But what happens is that instead both rotating independently they both rotate the same(second object around the first).

Original position of two objects:
[image: Starting position]

And this is how they look like when rotating: 
[image: As you can see the second object(cube) is rotating around the first(pyramid)]

I tried using a second LoadIdentity() function before drawing the second object to reset 
  the view?(I don't excatly understand the job of this function so i would greatly       appreciate if someone explained it to me), but then the second object isn't even drawn.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I am new to  OpenGL so it is probably some rookie mistake but i can't see it.

For reference i used this tutorial( Where you can see that LoadIdentity() is used two times ): http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/picking_alpha_blending_alpha_testing_sorting/16005/

Here is the code:

```
    System::Void Render(System::Void)
    {

        // Sfera sprem
        float kot1, kot2;
        float xx,yy,zz,xxp,yyp,zzp;

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // Počistimo ekran




            glLoadIdentity();
            glTranslatef(-2.0f, -1.0f, -6.0f); // Translacija objekta, parametri x,y,z os       

            glRotatef(rtri,0,1,0.0);
            //glScalef(risiPiramidaScaleX,risiPiramidaScaleY,risiPiramidaScaleZ);           
            glColor3f(risiPiramidaR,risiPiramidaG,risiPiramidaB);    


        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES); // Začetek Risanja trikotnikov


                // Stran 1
                glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // Top          
                glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.f, 0.0f); // Spodaj Levo  
                glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f); // Spodaj Desno

                // Stran 2


                glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f); // Top  
                glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.f, -2.0f); // Spodaj Levo   
                glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // Spodaj Desno

                // Stran 3

                glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.f, -2.0f); // Top
                glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.f, -2.0f); // Spodaj Levo 
                glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // Spodaj Desno

                // Stran 4


                glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.f, -2.0f); // Top                 
                glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.f, 0.0f); // Spodaj Levo 
                glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // Spodaj Desno

                // Stran 5


                glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f); // Top
                glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -2.0f); // Spodaj Levo    
                glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -2.0f); // Spodaj Desno


                // Stran 6


                glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -2.0f); // Top
                glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f); // Spodaj Levo    
                glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f); // Spodaj Desno




                glEnd(); // Konec Risanja Trikotnikov







                glTranslatef(3.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);             
            //  glScalef(risiKockaScaleX,risiKockaScaleY,risiKockaScaleZ);
                glRotatef(rquad,1,0,0.5);

                glColor3f(risiKockaR,risiKockaG,risiKockaB);    

                glBegin(GL_QUADS); // Risanje kocke
                glVertex3f( -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // Zgornji levi 
                glVertex3f(  1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // Zgornji desni
                glVertex3f(  1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f); // Spodnji desni
                glVertex3f( -1.0f, -1.0f , 0.0f); // Spodnji levi

                //stranica 2
                glVertex3f(  1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // Zgornji desni
                glVertex3f(  1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f); // spodnji desni                   
                glVertex3f(  1.0f, -1.0f, -2.0f); // Spodaj z os            
                glVertex3f(  1.0f,  1.0f, -2.0f); // Spodnji desni


                //str 3
                glVertex3f(   1.0f,  1.0f, -2.0f); // Zgornji desni
                glVertex3f(  -1.0f, 1.0f, -2.0f); // zgornji desni                  
                glVertex3f(  -1.0f, -1.0f, -2.0f); // Spodnji levi          
                glVertex3f(  1.0f, -1.0f, -2.0f); // Spodnji desni

                //str 4
                glVertex3f(  -1.0f, 1.0f, -2.0f); // Zgornji desni
                glVertex3f(  -1.0f, -1.0f, -2.0f); // zgornji desni                 
                glVertex3f(  -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f); // Spodnji levi           
                glVertex3f(  -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // Spodnji desni

                //str 5
                glColor3f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);    

                glVertex3f(  -1.0f, 1.0f, -2.0f); // Zgornji desni
                glVertex3f(  1.0f, 1.0f, -2.0); // zgornji desni                    
                glVertex3f(  1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // Spodnji levi         
                glVertex3f(  -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // Spodnji desni

                //str 6
                glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);    
                glVertex3f(  -1.0f, -1.0f, -2.0f); // Zgornji desni
                glVertex3f(  1.0f, -1.0f, -2.0); // zgornji desni                   
                glVertex3f(  1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f); // Spodnji levi            
                glVertex3f(  -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f); // Spodnji desni




            glEnd(); // Konec risanja kocke
        rquad += 0.2;
        rtri += 0.5;




    }
```

Comment: First translate to the center, then rotate and translate it back.

Comment: @ztirom Could you expand your answer? If i understand you correctly, i should translate object to the center(0,0,0??), then rotate it and then again translate it to its original position?

Comment: Yes, thats right. Try it by yourself. Mark a point on a paper, take a pencil and try to rotate. Once exactly at the marked point, once 10cm away from it, with the exact same rotation. You will see the difference.

Comment: Also note that in OpenGL matrix transformation operations effectively read from bottom to top due to the way column-major post-multiplication works. That is, the following sequence: `glLoadIdentity (); glTranslatef (1,1,1); glRotatef (...); glTranslatef (-1,-1,-1);` effectively translates the object to <-1,-1,-1> first, does some rotation and then translates back to the starting point. There is a matrix stack designed for this reason, you should look into `glPushMatrix (...)` and `glPopMatrix (...)` to keep local transformations local to individual objects.